# Python: Finding all possible unique two-index combinations in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-itertools

I have a numpy array that is roughly equivalent to:

```
data = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
```

I want to find all the unique **two-index** combinations of these values. In other words, I want all the possible combinations without repeating a row or column index (similar to correctly solving a Sudoku puzzle). For example, the desired output would be:

```
output >> ([1, 5, 9], [1, 6, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 6, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 5, 7])
```

and this output can be represented by their corresponding indices:
    ([0][0],[1][1],[2][2]), ([0][0],[1][2],[2][1]), ([0][1],[1][0],[2][2]), ([0][1],[1][2],[2][0]), ([0][2],[1][0],[2][1]), ([0][2],[1][1],[2][0])

I've tried using itertools.permutations, and while it does find all the possible permutations of my data for each unique row, it does not treat each column as unique)

I want **only one value from each row and each column**.

I’m fairly new to python, does anyone have a suggestion of how I might do this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We're not a code writing service, so please review [ask] and show us what you've tried.

Comment: take your output from itertools.permutations and pass it to the built in `set()` function, that will get rid of duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've tried calling itertools permutations on my array, but that returns all possible combinations where only the row is unique. I also began writing a recursive loop but then scrapped it early on: my real data set is very large and I need something more memory efficient.

Comment: If your real data set is very large this whole thing is bound to fail. Numbers of permutations grow **very** quickly.

Comment: Yes, since my set is large (approximately a 100 x 100 grid), I intend to control the otherwise huge number of permutations by 1) constraining the iterable to only find permutations where both the column and row are unique (as you have kindly helped me to do), and 2) by forcing that iterable to skip any permutation that contains the value 0 (I have previously removed a vast number of possibilities by converting values above a threshold to 0). Is there a way to call 'next()' on the '[[row[y] for row, y in zip... in permutations(range(len(dist)))]' if it would contain '0'? @Alex Hall

Comment: For example, for the data set `data = ([2,0,0,0], [0,3,0,4], [0,0,5,0], [0,6,0,7])` using `permutations(data)` returns 96 possibilities, using `[[row[y] for row, y in zip(data, perm)] for perm in permutations(range(len(data)))]` returns 24 possibilities, but ignoring/skipping possibilities containing `0` would return only 2 possibilities: `([2,3,5,7],[2,6,5,4])` @AlexHall

Comment: @SirJamesofGmail see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import permutations

data = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])

output = [[row[y] for row, y in zip(data, permutation)]
          for permutation in permutations(range(len(data)))]
```

EDIT: The problem has changed in the comments to only yield results that don't contain 0. Also since `len(data)` is 100 we can't produce all results using `permutations` like above and then filter them; that would take forever. They have to be correctly selected as we go, like so:

```
def get_nonzero_perms(data, remaining_indices=None):
    if not data:
        yield []
        return
    if remaining_indices is None:
        remaining_indices = list(range(len(data)))
    row = data[0]
    for i in remaining_indices:
        value = row[i]
        if value == 0:
            continue
        for perm in get_nonzero_perms(data[1:], [j for j in remaining_indices if j != i]):
            yield [value] + perm


for p in get_nonzero_perms(([2, 8, 0, 0], [0, 3, 9, 4], [0, 0, 5, 1], [4, 6, 0, 7])):
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 9, 1, 6]
[2, 4, 5, 6]
[8, 9, 1, 4]
[8, 4, 5, 4]
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of trying zip() in conjunction with my permutation iterable, thanks a lot!